# Problema ao rodar projeto - Caracteres especiais

Tags: java, string, codificação-de-caracteres, intellij-idea, encode

Migrei meu projeto para o Intellij IDEA e ao executar um código que deveria imprimir uma string com acentuação, eu tenho o retorno: "m?todo" (método). As classes exibem a acentuação corretamente mais ao chamar no console elas bugam.
Anexei algumas imagens do sistema:
[image: Encoding configuração]

[image: Minha classe que possui as strings com acentuação]

[image: Resultado]

Este é o retorno do console da IDE.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente verifique se os seus arquivos realmente estão encodados em `ISO-8859-1`, se sim, pode ser que o seu console esteja configurado para `UTF-8` ou algum outro tipo de codificação.

Você pode mudar o encoding do console adicionando a flag `-Dconsole.encoding` nos arquivos `idea.vmoptions` e `idea64.vmoptions` dentro de `[diretório de instalação do IDEA]\bin`.

Por exemplo, na minha máquina Windows com a versão `2016.2` do IntelliJ IDEA instalado no diretório padrão esses arquivos se encontram em:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions
```

Edite esses arquivos e adicione a linha `-Dconsole.encoding=ISO-8859-1`, e.g.:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dconsole.encoding=ISO-8859-1
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

---

**Referência**: [SOen - Intellij Idea incorrect encoding in console output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231291/664577)

Answer (score 0):

Clique com o botão direito do mouse no seu pacote do projeto. Vá em propriedades depois ache a codificação (se estiver em inglês 'encoding') e selecione ISO-8859-1 que é para sincronizar a codificação do texto.

[Fonte](http://respostas.guj.com.br/5717-caracteres-especiais---acentos-dao-erro-nas-palavras)